# Doubt in independence of 2 random variables

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, expected-value

If 2 random variables are independent, then $f(x,y) = f(x)f(y)$. Is converse true?

$F(x,y)=F(x)F(y)$. Is converse true?

$E(x,y)=E(x)E(y)$. Is converse true?

where $F$ is cdf and $f$ is pdf

I recently started studying probability and statistics. kindly explain

Comment: $f(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$ is the definition of independence. Moreover it is hard to tell what you mean by “converse” in here?

Comment: If f(x,y)=f(x)f(y) then can we say x and y are independent rvs. Also sir pls see comment below answer.

Comment: Yes, this is the definition. This is *how* we tell they are independent.

Comment: sir what if F(x) changes wrto y domain. Pls see my comment below the given answer

Comment: @Tim pls see this - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/476878/compute-16-varx32-vary-for-given-bivariate-cdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the explanation in the wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#/For_real_valued_random_variables), you'll see that for the first and second statements, it is 'if and only if'. So, yes converse is true.

But, $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$ only means that $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=0$ i.e. $X,Y$ are uncorrelated. It doesn't guarantee independence.

Comment: sir if F(x,y)=F(x)F(y) (given F(y)=1) but interval wise F(x) changes based on y then can we say x,y are independent randomvariables. FOr ex., F(x,y) = 0 if x<0 or y<0; $\frac{1-e^{-x}}{4}, x>0, 0 \leq y <1$ and $1-e^{-x}, x \geq 0,  y  \geq 1$

Comment: sir pls explain.........

Comment: @NascimentodeCos $F(x)$ cannot change based on $y$, because it is the CDF of $X$ only. And, given $F(y)=1$ doesn't make sense, because for independence $F(x,y)=F(x)F(y)$ should hold for all $x,y$

Comment: understood now. thank you sir